# Why did the brothers get the money in their bags, and who were they speaking to when they explain the situation?

Tags: yosef, egypt, miketz

What was the purpose of the brothers having the money in their bags? It did not get them back to Egypt, they went back for food. So what was the point of this whole ordeal? Further, when they explain the situation, it says they speak to the one 'in charge' of Yosef HaTzadikk's house - who was this, and how did he know they received their money originally.  (Bonus: *Was* the money actually received, or were they just saying that to make them calm?)

Comment: Which time are you talking about? Do you mean the first time when Yoshef had Menasheh put the original money back in the bags ([Miketz 42:25](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8237/showrashi/true#v25)) or the second time  when he added the cup in Binyamin's bag as well as the money?

Answer (score 2):

Yosef commanded Menashe to put the money in the bags as shown in [Miketz 42:25](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8237/showrashi/true#v25) in order to set the brothers up for the next time that they came. Yaakov suspected that something was wrong so he sent the original money back with the brothers as in [Miketz 43:12](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8238/jewish/Chapter-43.htm/showrashi/true#v12) besides the new money. When they returned to Egypt, Menashe in [Miketz 43:23](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8238/jewish/Chapter-43.htm/showrashi/true#v23) pretended to have received the original money in order to set up the next step.

Indeed they denied the second charge in [Miketz 44:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8239/jewish/Chapter-44.htm/showrashi/true#v8) since they had tried to return all the money.

All of this was part of Yosef's plan to test that the brothers had truly repented of what they had done to him and to see that they would protect Binyamin.

Comment: Could you explain this further? How does it "set things up" for the next time? How does this test the brothers' repentance?

Comment: @MichoelR The next step was to accuse the brothers of stealing the money and blaming Binyomin. He needed to see if they had conquered the jealousy that led them to throw him into the pit and (ass Yosef believed) led them to selling him to the caravan going to Egypt.

Comment: He didn't accuse the brothers of stealing the money. On the contrary, they used the money as a proof that they had not stolen the goblet.